# One node surprisingly running out of disk space

Tags: cardano-node, stake-pool, ubuntu, linux

I had two cardano-node instances running via kvm on one physical machine.
Both nodes were running on mainnet for a while before I switched them over to testnet (to prepare for turning these into a stake pool).

I gave both environments (labelled **BlockProducer** and **Relay**) the same resources, incl. 150 GB of disk space.
[image: hard disk space for virtual environments]

When logging into both environments, I noticed that BlockProducer's cardano-node process crashed with a `FileSystemError`, stating that there is no space left on the device.
Restarting the process (also after rebooting BlockProducer) did not change this.

[image: FsDeviceFull]

These are the outputs for `df -h` and `du -h -d 1` in the respective cardano-node directories. Left is the (working) Relay, while the right side shows the BlockProducer environment.[image: Relay and BlockProducer comparison]

The host system running the kvm daemon still has 210 GB of available disk space.
Did I simply under-provision the virtual disks or what is going on here?

Why is Relay still running though? I installed the same software and configured both environments the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Disk space issue:

Each system only has 73GB maximum on / (which is where you are running from).
The live Cardano chain is now 50GB on it's own. I'm not sure of the testdb size.

Make the / volume larger on each system eg 120GB maybe.

2. Differences between BP and Relay system:

The BP system has used 70GB of / while the Relay has used 65GB of /

So, what has used the extra 5GB somewhere on the BP system?
Left over logs or code?

cd to /home and do a 'du -h .' there to see if you can spot if the space has been used by a different user.

If not obvious there then you will need to review other directories off of / to narrow down where the extra 5GB has been used.
Often /var/log can use a lot of disk space logging things.
Also check /tmp

Comment: That's the thing though, I provisioned 150 GB for each of the environments.

Comment: Yes, the *whole* environment may be 150G, but as @MC_Brisbane points out, the partition where the `node` is storing its data is smaller.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out which files are filling up the disk.

A command like:

```
find / -type f -printf "%15s    %p\n" | sort -nr | head -30;
```

might help.